# How to calculate CSS rotate method degree using Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations, trigonometry, rotatetransform

Following is my speedometer. I want to calculate the degree of the pointer which will be used in CSS `transform:rotate()` property.

[Speedometer Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbXfi.png)

to keep the pointer at 300 score my degree is -85 i.e.`transform:rotate(-85deg)` and to keep it at 900 my degree is 85 i.e.`transform:rotate(85deg)`.

So now I want to dynamically calculate the degree based on the score. If the score is below 300, I will use -85deg and if its above 900 then I will use 85deg. How can I calculate degree if the score is between 300 to 900 and degree should be between -85 to 85. I am not good at trigonometry.

I tried to calculate the using percentage but I think, I am doing that calculation wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the 0 to 100 percentage of the value in the range of `300 to 900`, then use that percentage to get the value of where that percentage sits in the angle range, then simple check on min and max constraints:

```js
function getRotation(value, options) {
  const result = options.range.min + (options.range.max - options.range.min) * (((value - options.value.min) * 100) / (options.value.max - options.value.min) / 100)
  
  if (result < options.range.min) return options.range.min
  if (result > options.range.max) return options.range.max
  return result
}

const options = {
  value: {
    min: 300,
    max: 900
  },
  range: {
    min: -85,
    max: 85
  }
}

console.log(getRotation(0, options))    // -85
console.log(getRotation(300, options))  // -85
console.log(getRotation(600, options))  // 0
console.log(getRotation(900, options))  // 85
console.log(getRotation(1000, options)) // 85
```